# DB-helvetica font is not working in iPhone - Xamarin form

Tags: iphone, fonts

I am using custom DB-Helvetica in my Xamarin forms app. I have added .ttf file in iOS and Android. For Android it is working as expected. But for iOS I am not able to see the font.

I have added the font in info.plist and added those resources as Bundle Resource.

Answer (score 0):

Without having more information about how you load them (code) it's difficult to know what's happening. However, you load fonts on iOS in a different way. That is a common issue when loading fonts. Also, be sure of the name you use for that font.

An example of how you load fonts on 3 platforms.

```
<OnPlatform x:Key="MaterialFontFamily" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="Material Design Icons" />
    <On Platform="Android" Value="materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf#Material Design Icons" />
    <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf#Material Design Icons" />
</OnPlatform>
```